# iOS screen size in code, is this optional?

Tags: ios, screen-orientation

In some apps theres settings for screen sizes. Vs regular constraint settings, whats the advantage vs disadvantage?

example:

```
 struct Setting {
        struct Small {
            static let phoneSE: CGFloat = 11.0
            static let phone: CGFloat = 13.0
            static let phonePlus: CGFloat = 14.0
        }

        struct Medium {
            static let phoneSE: CGFloat = 12.0
            static let phone: CGFloat = 14.0
            static let phonePlus: CGFloat = 15.0
        }

        struct Large {
            static let phoneSE: CGFloat = 13.0
            static let phone: CGFloat = 15.0
            static let phonePlus: CGFloat = 16.0
        }
```

These values are specific font size values.

The values often change for the purpose, some values might be font size or img sizes. Is something like this a good practice or overkill?

Answer (score 2):

It *usually isn't* "good practice" to code against specific devices. Or in other words, it *is* "good practice to code against size classes (using auto layout constraints) and use Dynamic Type (instead of specific font sizes) where possible. Why? Because when Apple releases something new - like the 10.5 inch iPad Pro last April or the rumored iPhone Pro this September - you won't have to do much, if anything to your code.

It will "just work".

That said, here's some reasons you may need to code against specific devices - or more accurately, specific screen sizes:

- UI changes for orientation on an iPad and iPhone "Plus". Size classes are always regular no matter the orientation.
- Font sizes, like in your example.

I'm sure there's more. But in these two cases - and really, in all cases - it's "good practice" to *try hard* to use what Apple gives you. Refactor your UI if possible. Save on unnecessary ongoing maintenance.

Comment: Accessibility, i.e., Dynamic Type, is also a consideration.

Comment: Agreed. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: That's what I thought. If default sizes are fine and I only have to make a few global constraints, then my code is easier to maintain. And since iOS updates might and often change font sizes for some items...I don't have any real use to force a size.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements.

If you need to display different size depend on device you can create structure for that if not than you can use fix size.